# Receptive Field and ConvNets

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

So I was reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf

*VERY DEEP CONVOLUTIONAL NETWORKS FOR LARGE-SCALE IMAGE RECOGNITION
Karen Simonyan∗ & Andrew Zisserman+
Visual Geometry Group, Department of Engineering Science, University of Oxford*

and at a point it mentions: *"It is easy to see that a stack of two 3 × 3 conv. layers (without spatial pooling in between) has an effective receptive field of 5 × 5; three such layers have a 7 × 7 effective receptive field."*

I don't understand how these effective receptive fields are calculated in relation to the convolutions / convolution units.

Comment: Please add a complete citation for the paper.

Comment: @gung I kinda added it now, not sure if you meant that though.

Answer (score 1):

When you center a 3x3 filter in the top left corner of a region then that filter extends one unit above and one unit to the left of the original region. So, convolving a 3x3 filter with another 3x3 filter will produce a 5x5 filter since the 3x3 filter has been extended by one pixel in each direction.

If the size of the filter is an odd number of pixels ($n$) then it will increase the receptive field by $n - 1$ pixels.

Comment: I totally understand adding 3x3 conv layer increases the receptive field from 3x3 to 5x5 to 7x7 and so on. By I can't understand what you're saying "If the size of the filter is an odd number of pixels (n) then it will increase the receptive field by n−1 pixels".  when kernel is 3x3, the receptive increase at first stage 5x5 - 3x3 = 16. Why do you say it's n-1? (if we say n = 9, it doesn't match either)